# How do I put a multidimensional array of nodes into a Stack?

Tags: java, arrays, object, stack, multidimensional-array

I'm a bit new to java, and I'm having problems putting my array of nodes into a stack.

Here I create globals `myNode` and the stack that should hold an array of `myNode`s.

```
static myNode[][] cells = new myNode[9][9];
static Stack<myNode[][]> myStack = new Stack<myNode[][]>();
```

I instantiate each element in the array and populate the `cells[row][column].values`:

```
for(int row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
        for(int column = 0; column < 9; column++)
        {
            //instantiate each element
            cells[row][column] = new myNode();
            cells[row][column].initialize();
            //set myNodes values of each element from given input
            String value = txt[row][column].getText(); //gets string from JTextBox
            if (!value.equals("")) //empty cells will equal 0;
            {
                cells[row][column].value = Integer.parseInt(txt[row][column].getText());
            }
        }
    }
```

I try to push the cells array, and then revert back later (maybe I'm doing this wrong?):

```
cells[0][0].value = 9;

//push cells (save state)
myStack.push(cells);

//change cells
cells[0][0].value = 12345; //for example

//pop cells (revert state)
cells = myStack.pop();

System.out.println(Integer.toString(cells[0][0].value)); //will print 12345!
```

But this prints a value of 12345 instead of the desired 9, showing the problem I am encountering. What am I doing wrong? Is it because it is pushing a pointer on the stack?

Comment: Indeed, you keep in the stack only a reference to the actual object, not a copy of it, so you will modify the same object.

Comment: lol I love how you have this huge question and the answer is, to your very last sentence: yes.

Comment: (If you don't want it to use a pointer, make a copy of the object and push that.)

Comment: Thanks guys! I'm glad I made it easy for you :) Is there any easier way to copy the array of myNodes without using for loops and doing all that work? Like: myNode newNode = cell.copy();

Comment: I guess, but you would still have to use at least one loop. Loop through the rows and copy the columns of those rows using Arrays.copyOf

Comment: Seems like this is going to be a sudoku solver!?